# Using Azure Key Vault in a separate Azure Web App

Tags: drupal, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have setup a Web App on Azure in a resource group and it doesn't have any connection with Azure Active Directory.

I have added Azure Key Vault into the same resource group where the web app is placed. The thing is that I cannot find a way to use Azure Key Vault in my web app. All the documentations I have found, are explaining how to use it with the apps in the Active Directory.

Does Azure Key Vault work with seperate web apps? If so how can I use it in my app. I will be setting up Drupal and secure the keys with Azure Key Vault.

It would be great if someone could show me a path to take on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which keys are you referring to?

Comment: @KaushalKumarPanday I'd like to store any keys like database connection strings, secret keys and such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started#register):

> Applications that use a key vault ***must*** authenticate by using a token from Azure Active Directory. To do this, the owner of the application ***must*** first register the application in their Azure Active Directory.

Also, Key Vault is not supported today in the PHP SDK. See [Keyvault support #898](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/issues/898). You'll need to work with it by using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/).

Comment: Thank a lot, you are right, I've managed to get the keys using only REST API and had to create and application in Azure AD.